# Error when fitting a bivariate latent change score model using r package lcsm

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to fit a bivariate latent change score model for two time points using the lcsm package but am running into an error.

When I try to extract fit statistics, I get the following error:

```
Error: No glance method for objects of class character
```

When I try to extract parameter estimates, I get the following error:

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class character
```

Does anyone know how to fix these errors? Thank you!

Here is my syntax:

```
lavaan_bi_lcsm_fit <- 

specify_bi_lcsm(df_wide,
timepoints = 2,
var_x = c("srpf_ses1","srpf_ses2"),
model_x = list(alpha_constant = TRUE, 
beta = TRUE, 
phi = TRUE),
var_y = c("avg_hippocampus1","avg_hippocampus2"),
model_y = list(alpha_constant = TRUE, 
beta = TRUE, 
phi = TRUE),  
coupling = list(delta_lag_xy = TRUE, 
delta_lag_yx = TRUE))

extract_fit(lavaan_bi_lcsm_fit)
extract_param(lavaan_bi_lcsm_fit)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main issue is that the function `specify_bi_lcsm()` returns the *lavaan* syntax for your specified model as a *character* object and the functions `extract_fit()` and `extract_param()` are expecting a *lavaan* object that contains information about your fitted models.

I assume you were aiming to fit a model using the `fit_bi_lcsm()` function but instead accidentally used `specify_bi_lcsm()`.

I think you only need to make a few small changes to fix the error messages:

1. Replace `specify_bi_lcsm()` with `fit_bi_lcsm()`
2. Remove the line `timepoints = 2,` from your code, as this argument is only needed for generating *lavaan* syntax but not for fitting a model. The `fit_bi_lcsm()` automatically detects the number of time points based on the number of variables you specify in the `var_x` and `var_y` arguments:

Something like this should hopefully work:

```
lavaan_bi_lcsm_fit <- fit_bi_lcsm(
  data = df_wide,
  var_x = c("srpf_ses1", "srpf_ses2"),
  model_x = list(alpha_constant = TRUE, 
                 beta = TRUE, 
                 phi = TRUE),
  var_y = c("avg_hippocampus1", "avg_hippocampus2"),
  model_y = list(alpha_constant = TRUE, 
                 beta = TRUE, 
                 phi = TRUE),  
  coupling = list(delta_lag_xy = TRUE, 
                  delta_lag_yx = TRUE)
)
```

Now the `lavaan_bi_lcsm_fit` is a *lavaan* object (or 'Formal class lavaan' in R language) and you should be able to extract the fit statistics and model parameter estimates (provided your model can be estimated):

```
extract_fit(lavaan_bi_lcsm_fit)
extract_param(lavaan_bi_lcsm_fit)
```